# TSQL - how to execute a query as a variable?

Tags: t-sql, variables

```
DECLARE @query as varchar(200);
SET @query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table';
```

How can I execute `@query`, and additionally, is there way to store the query result directly when assigning the variable?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) with an `output` parameter to retrieve the scalar result.

```
DECLARE @query as nvarchar(200), @count int;
SET @query = N'SELECT @count = COUNT(*)  FROM table';

EXEC sp_executesql @query, 
                   N'@count int OUTPUT', 
                   @count = @count OUTPUT

SELECT @count AS [@count]
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure if i understand the code propertly, does it asign query result into count variable, by OUTPUT?

Comment: @Malyo - It declares a variable `@count` in the outer scope. This gets passed as an output parameter in the `sp_executesql` call which means the assignment to the output parameter is propagated to that variable. See [TSQL Basics II - Parameter Passing Semantics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/06/09/624531.aspx) for more about `OUTPUT` parameters.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it like this:

```
exec (@query)
```

or, preferably, like this:

```
execute sp_executesql @query
```

For more info, check [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

Try this : 
`declare @query as varchar(200) 
select @query = COUNT(*) from table`